# Bot Framework Application doesn't reply to messages when published to azure

Tags: c#, botframework

I have bot that working fine with local machine when published to local machine.

```
[15:14:02] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate] 
[15:14:06] Warning: The Bot Framework State API is not recommended for production environments, and may be deprecated in a future release. Learn how to implement your own storage adapter. 
[15:14:06] <- GET 200 getConversationData 
[15:14:06] <- GET 200 getPrivateConversationData 
[15:14:07] <- GET 200 getUserData
```

When I publish this to Azure bot do not reply to messages, status is becoming like this:

```
[15:24:10] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate] 
[15:24:10] -> POST 200 [conversationUpdate] 
[15:24:13] -> POST 200 [message] hello
```

Application insights register message events, but nothing happens after this event.

All the web.configs are copied correctly.

Comment: I guess you are still using the emulator, so, have you setup Ngrok?

Comment: @NicolasR i tried emulator and telegram chat. ngrok is set up, but it still not working, no exception. application insights showing that message received, but nothing happens after

Comment: When you are connecting with the emulator to the published bot, are you providing the appid and password?  (also: is the appid and password in the web.config or app settings on azure?)

Comment: @EricDahlvang yes, they are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a bot application using basic template in visual studio and do a test to [connect the emulator to bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-debug-emulator) running on localhost and Azure, and I can send and receive messages as expected.

[image]

The bot is a web API with endpoint `"your_bots_hostname/api/messages",` and we can host it on Azure with App Service, you can try to [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) your code and check if the code is executed as expected.

Besides, if possible, you can try to create an new bot application with basic template, then publish to Azure, and test if you can send and receive messages via emulator to your new bot hosting on local and Azure.

Comment: Fei Han that worked. I do not understand that magic. previous I have started in the same way and it did not work. this one works.